# Entity Framework Code First with link Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Currently I have 3 tables (and representative objects).

These are 2 objects, and a link table. This works for me, but the data I get back from the database is in an unwieldy structure / format.

My Domain object should be;

```
[Question]
  int id
  string QuestionText
  ICollection<Answers> Answers

[Answer]
  int id
  string AnswerText
  int NextQuestion
```

My join is below. Basically I am joining my Questions to teh Link Table, which creates an object that is [Question, Link]. then I join Answers into this, so I get an object that is effectively;
    [Answer, [[Question], [Link]]

Apart from seemign to be relatively slow to execute, this code also needs a lot of manipulation from me to convert the data into my internal structure.

```
var dbModels = await Task.Run(() => _context.QuestionsInSet
            .Join(_context.LinkQuestionsAnswers, 
            q=>q.Id, qa=>qa.AnswerId,
            (q,qa) => new {Question=q, LinkQuestionsAnswers = qa})
            .Join(_context.Answers, qa=>qa.LinkQuestionsAnswers.AnswerId, a=>a.Id,
            (qa, a) => new {Link=qa, Answer=a})
            .Where(z=>z.Link.LinkQuestionsAnswers.SetId== id)

            );
```

Is there any way of simplifying this using annotations, or mapping using the ModelBuilder in the context? the only way i can see of simplifying this is to break it down into multiple database calls. (get all the questions that belong to a set, then for each question, get all the answers). Though whilst that is more maintainable, it is even slower as there are multiple database queries.

Comment: theorically, if I welle understand the need, `_ctx.Questions.Include(q => q.Answers).Where(q => IdList.Contains(questionId))` should allow to get all question and answers for a set of question Ids.

Comment: I can't make it work using the syntax you have suggested, but thanks.